# DropdownList disabled based on some condition in kendo grid

Tags: html, angular6, kendo-grid

How to disable dropdownlist in kendo grid based on some condition.

In my code when status is Reject then dropdownlist should be enabled otherwise disabled. But when I set the **DDLdisabled** true then it set all dropdownlist in grid is enabled.

I want only when I checked Reject or Done radio button then only that respective row dropdownlist enabled or disabled.
How to do it?

Please help me..

HTML Code :

```
    <kendo-grid-column field="Action" title="Reject" width="120">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="SelectedRejectedReason" title="SelectedRejectedReasons" width="120" >
    </kendo-grid-column>

    <kendo-grid-column title="CRT Actions" width="150">
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
        <!--{{rowIndex}}-->
        <input type="radio" [name]="generate(rowIndex, 'status')" [id]="generate(rowIndex, 'done')" value="single" class="k-radio"
               (change)="setSelectableSettings1($event,dataItem)">
        <label class="k-radio-label lbl" [for]="generate(rowIndex, 'done')"> Done </label>

        <input type="radio" [name]="generate(rowIndex, 'status')" [id]="generate(rowIndex, 'reject')" value="multiple" class="k-radio"
               (change)="setSelectableSettings1($event,dataItem)">
        <label class="k-radio-label" [for]="generate(rowIndex, 'reject')"> Reject </label>
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>

    <kendo-grid-column title="Status Comment" width="200"   >
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-dataItem >
        <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="statusCommentSource"   [disabled]="DDLdisabled"
        [textField]="'NewRejectionReason'"
        [valueField]="'RejectionCommentId'"      
        (selectionChange)="setComment($event,dataItem)">
        >
          </kendo-dropdownlist>
    </ng-template>    
  </kendo-grid-column>
```

TS File Code :

```
public setSelectableSettings1(e, dataItem): void {
    this.gridActionEventData.dataItem = dataItem;
    if (e.target.checked) {
      if (e.target.id.indexOf("done") > -1) { dataItem.Action = 'Done';  }
      else { dataItem.Action = 'Reject'; 
             this.description = dataItem;             
            }
    } else {
      if (e.target.id.indexOf("done") > -1) { dataItem.Action = 'Reject';  }
      else { dataItem.Action = 'Done';  }
    };   

    if(dataItem.Action == "Reject" )
      {
        this.DDLdisabled = false;
      }
      else{ this.DDLdisabled = true;}
  }

public setComment(e, dataItem): void
  {
      this.SelectedRejectedReason = e.NewRejectionReason;
      dataItem.SelectedRejectedReason = e.NewRejectionReason;      
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.SelectedRejectedReason));
  }
```

Output :

[OutputScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MQgq.png)

Answer (score 0):

```js
//id-> which dropdown you want to disable/enable

if (your conditon) {
  $("#id").kendoDropDownList({ enable: false });
}
else{
  $("#id").kendoDropDownList({ enable: false });
}
```